# Find the $\mathfrak B$-matrix for the transformation $x\mapsto Ax$ given matrix $A$ and a set of vectors for $\mathfrak B$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Find the $\mathfrak B$-matrix for the transformation $x\mapsto Ax$, where $\mathfrak B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3\\5\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\2&4\end{bmatrix}.$

Not looking for an answer as one is already provided $\begin{bmatrix}7&12\\-1&-2\end{bmatrix}$, but I don't even know what is being asked here. I have not been able to find a similar example problem in the text or online. I may just be severely misunderstanding the content of the section.

Comment: Have you encoutered the concept of a *basis* yet?

Comment: @mrtaurho Yes I have.  Thanks for the formatting by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given linear transformation $x\mapsto Ax$, where $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with real entries, and a set of $2$ vectors $\mathfrak B$. The transformation is w.r.t. to the standard basis $B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ and as you can check, the vectors of $\mathfrak B$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^2$, clearly different from the canonical basis.

Your task is to find how $A$ transforms $\Bbb R^2$ w.r.t. to the new basis $\mathfrak B$ (the $\mathfrak B$-matrix). This process is known as [*change of basis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis), and I find the following diagram quite illuminating
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Bbb R^2_B @>{A}>> \Bbb R^2_B\\
@V{M_B^{\mathfrak B}}VV @VV{M_B^{\mathfrak B}}V\\
\Bbb R^2_{\mathfrak B} @>>{\mathfrak A}> \Bbb R^2_{\mathfrak B}
\end{CD}
$$
Here $\Bbb R^2_A$ and $\Bbb R^2_{\mathfrak B}$ refer to $\Bbb R^2$ w.r.t. to the standard basis $B$ and to the given basis $\mathfrak B$, $A$ is the given linear transformation (or rather its transformation matrix) and $\mathfrak A$ is the matrix you are asked to find. The interesting thing is the matrix $M_B^{\mathfrak B}$ which transforms the basis $B$ into the basis $\mathfrak B$, by sending $[1,0]^\top\mapsto[2,3]^\top$ and $[0,1]^\top\mapsto[3,5]^\top$. From the diagram it is clear that $\mathfrak A=M_B^{\mathfrak B}A(M_B^{\mathfrak B})^{-1}$ as we expect that it does not matter in which way we go from $\Bbb R^2_B$ to $\Bbb R^2_{\mathfrak B}$ (the diagram commutes).

Now, take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\2&4\end{bmatrix}$ and $M_B^{\mathfrak B}=\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\3&5\end{bmatrix}$. Compute $(M_B^{\mathfrak B})^{-1}$ (it should be $\begin{bmatrix}5&-3\\-3&2\end{bmatrix}$), and then you obtain $\mathfrak A$  as above. The key is the commuting diagram which, by the way, is a great tool to remember what really is going on.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the detailed reply, the question is quite clear now.  Screencapping that diagram.

Comment: @Dudeguy21 Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You have$$A.\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}11\\16\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }A.\begin{bmatrix}3\\5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}18\\26\end{bmatrix}.$$But$$\begin{bmatrix}11\\16\end{bmatrix}=7\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}3\\5\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{bmatrix}18\\26\end{bmatrix}=12\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix}3\\5\end{bmatrix},$$which means that the matrix of your linear transformation with respect to $\mathfrak B$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}7&12\\-1&-2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: So the 'B-matrix' is shorthand for the matrix of the transformation with respect to the basis provided?  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's just it.